# Data annotations description in EditorFor net-core

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, popover

The issue is getting the data annotations 'Display(Description)' attribute from my model via the EditorFor extension. All methods I've found have involved passing the actual model to the method.

```
public class MyModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Title", Description = "A popover message"), Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Using editor templates: View/Shared/EditorTemplates/String.cshtml

```
@model System.String

@{
    var popoverText = "_ Get model data annotations description here? _";
}

@Html.LabelFor(x => x, (string)ViewData["LabelText"])
<i class="bi bi-info-circle" data-bs-toggle="popover" title="Info" data-bs-content="@popoverText"></i>
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

So within the editor for I want to get the description field and put it within a bootstrap popover. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as:

```
var popoverText = ViewData.ModelMetadata.Description;
```